# DFS algorithm needs to be improved

Tags: c, depth-first-search

The problem is about saving [James Bond](http://www.patest.cn/contests/mooc-ds2015spring/06-%E5%9B%BE2). My code gets the right answer only in some special occasions. I spent so much time but I didn't find any mistake in my algorithm. I need your help. Thanks.

Here is the request of the problem.

.......................................

This time let us consider the situation in the movie "Live and Let Die" in which James Bond, the world's most famous spy, was captured by a group of drug dealers. He was sent to a small piece of land at the center of a lake filled with crocodiles. There he performed the most daring action to escape -- he jumped onto the head of the nearest crocodile! Before the animal realized what was happening, James jumped again onto the next big head... Finally he reached the bank before the last crocodile could bite him (actually the stunt man was caught by the big mouth and barely escaped with his extra thick boot).

Assume that the lake is a 100 by 100 square one. Assume that the center of the lake is at (0,0) and the northeast corner at (50,50). The central island is a disk centered at (0,0) with the diameter of 15. A number of crocodiles are in the lake at various positions. Given the coordinates of each crocodile and the distance that James could jump, you must tell him whether or not he can escape.

Input Specification:

Each input file contains one test case. Each case starts with a line containing two positive integers N (<=100), the number of crocodiles, and D, the maximum distance that James could jump. Then N lines follow, each containing the (x, y) location of a crocodile. Note that no two crocodiles are staying at the same position.

Output Specification:

For each test case, print in a line "Yes" if James can escape, or "No" if not.

Sample Input 1:

14 20

25 -15

-25 28

8 49

29 15

-35 -2

5 28

27 -29

-8 -28

-20 -35

-25 -20

-13 29

-30 15

-35 40

12 12

Sample Output 1:

Yes

Sample Input 2:

4 13

-12 12

12 12

-12 -12

12 -12

Sample Output 2:

No

.......................................

Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
    #include <malloc.h>
    #include <math.h>

    typedef struct Node{
        int x;
        int y;
    } Position;

    int result;
    Position beast[1000];
    int visited[1000];
    int NumOfB, JumpAb;

    void dfs(int i){
        int j;
        if (Available(i)){
            visited[i]=1;
            if (Save(i)) {
                result = 1;
                printf("Yes");
            }
        }
        for(j = 0;j<NumOfB;j++)
            if(!visited[j])
                dfs(j);
    }
    int Available(int i){
        int j;
        double d_x,d_y;
        for (j=0;j<NumOfB;j++){
            d_x = beast[i].x - beast[j].x;
            d_y = beast[i].y - beast[j].y;
            if (((d_x*d_x+d_y*d_y)<JumpAb*JumpAb)&& visited[j]==1){
                return 1;
            }

        }
        return 0;
    }
    int Save(int i){
        if ((abs(50-abs(beast[i].x))<=JumpAb)||((abs(50-abs(beast[i].y)))<=JumpAb))
            return 1;
        else 
            return 0;
    }
    int FirstJump(int i){
        if (((beast[i].x*beast[i].x)+(beast[i].y*beast[i].y))<=JumpAb*JumpAb){
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }   
    }
    int main(){
        result = 0;
        scanf("%d %d",&NumOfB,&JumpAb); 
        int i;
        Position* p =NULL;
        for (i=0;i<NumOfB;i++){
            p = (Position*)malloc(sizeof(Position));
            scanf("%d %d",&p->x,&p->y);
        }
        for (i=0;i<NumOfB;i++){
            visited[i] = 0;
        }
        for(i = 0;i<NumOfB;i++){
          if(!visited[i] && FirstJump(i)){
            visited[i] = 1;
            dfs(i);
           }
        }
        if (result==0){
            printf("No");
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You really should say, at least, what you expect your code to do and what it outputs now.  Otherwise, it is hard for us to guess what you want.  (You'll please forgive me for not following a random link while at work given some of the typos/spelling errors in your post.)

Comment: You never reset `visited`. In a typical maze-finding code like this, you should clean up the visited flag when you backtrack from unsuccessful solutions, so that later paths can visit the node again.

Comment: I hope you're not cheating on your programming test by asking us to fix your code problems :)

Comment: of course i am not cheating.To improve my coding ability I find some tests on OJ.